# Adjust width of textbox according to page width

Tags: textbox, adjustment

I am trying to get the textbox to fill up the entire width but I do not know how to do it. I am attaching a screenshot below I want the text box to fill up the entire container and be responsive as well(I mean adjust the width of the textbox automatically).there is a gap between the textbox and the advance search button. Also I'm using bootstrap 2.2 if that can help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 has a [calc](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) function that can help you with this, see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XWVygF4nbpmt0FsQvg5Z?p=preview)